# Mistake in wording for partial_ordering on cppreference

Tags: c++, c++20

In CPP Reference's description of [std::partial_ordering](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/compare/partial_ordering) it says:

> The behavior of a program that attempts to compare a `partial_ordering` with anything other than the integer literal `​0​` is undefined.

But right afterwards it documents an equality operator that compares two instances of `partial_ordering`. This is a contradiction in my opinion.

I understand what they're trying to say: if you are comparing to an integer, it must be the literal `0`, otherwise it's undefined behavior. But the way it's worded now makes it seem like comparing two `partial_ordering` instances to each other is undefined behavior as well.

Am I misreading something? Does "attempt to compare" not encompass equality comparison?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The quoted sentence was added before [P1614R2](https://wg21.link/p1614r2) (which added comparisons between two `partial_ordering` values) was adopted, and didn't get updated after that.

You are welcome to improve the wording.

Answer (score 1):

This sentence is clearly intended to refer only to the comparison functions that take a template parameter.  The [draft standard](https://eel.is/c++draft/cmp.categories#pre-3) says:

> The relational and equality operators for the comparison category types are specified with an anonymous parameter of unspecified type.
> This type shall be selected by the implementation such that these parameters can accept literal `0` as a corresponding argument.
>
> [Example 1: `nullptr_t` meets this requirement. — end example]
>
> In this context, the behavior of a program that supplies an argument
> other than a literal `0` is undefined.

Comparison with other objects of the same type is not restricted.